# Align cells into same column based on key

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where every cell is a key-value pair i.e.

```
df <- data.frame(q1= c("1:4", "1:4", "1:6", "1:7"),
                 q2= c("2:2", "2:4", "3:1", "2:1"),
                 q3= c("3:1", "4:1", "4:2", "3:2"),
                 q4= c("4:3", NA, NA, "4:2"))
```

I am looking for a way to re-arrange/shift the cells based on the key of every cell, such that all cells with key 3 are shifted into column q3, cells with key 4 are shifted into column q4.

Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(q1= c("1:4", "1:4", "1:6", "1:7"),
                 q2= c("2:2", "2:4", NA, "2:1"),
                 q3= c("3:1", NA, "3:1", "3:2"),
                 q4= c("4:3", "4:1", "4:2", "4:2"))
```

note that the real data contains many thousands of entries so manually re-arranging cells is not viable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-id) |> 
  drop_na(value) |> 
  mutate(name = paste0("q", stringr::str_extract(value, "^\\d{1,2}"))) |> 
  complete(name, id) |> 
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 4 × 5
     id q1    q2    q3    q4   
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1:4   2:2   3:1   4:3  
2     2 1:4   2:4   NA    4:1  
3     3 1:6   NA    3:1   4:2  
4     4 1:7   2:1   3:2   4:2
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution - could you elaborate on what the line "mutate(name = paste0("q", stringr::str_extract(value, "^.")))" means/does exactly? Specifically, the part of the expression  "^." - what is this? What does the ^ do here?

Also I noticed that if some keys are higher than 10 (11:2, 12:5), these will be mis-categorized as being part of q1 column (instead of getting their own q11 and q12 columns). How might one fix this? I suspect the problem is in the line noted above but I am not sure how to modify it.

Comment: "^." is a form of regular expression, or regex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression `^` means "start of string" and `.` means "any one character value". So it translates to "extract the first value in the string".

Comment: "Also I noticed that if some keys are higher than 10 (11:2, 12:5), these will be mis-categorized as being part of q1 column" I've edited my answer to capture either one or two digit numbers. `^\\d{1,2}` means "starting with any 1 or 2 digit number".